# To display multiple charts like Bar chart,Pie chart, line chart in a single collection view in a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, charts, collectionview

The requirement of my app is such that I need show different charts such as Pie chart, Line Chart , Bar chart etc.. in a collection view in a view controller.
I'm planning on using the most used library to create the charts https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts .To implement each type of chart individually on a page, we have to create a UIView of the chart's class .For example to implement a pie chart we have to create a view of class PieChartView.
My question is if we want different charts in a single collection view,How can we implement it? Since i'm new to swift development code samples would really help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the view controller that displays the collection view is claled StatsVC, then you need to add a collection View to it in interface builder, click on the collectionViewCell and give it a reuse identifier (e.g. chartCell) then in code:

`class StatcVC:UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
//create your charts here and put them in an array to be easier later on
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int -> Int {
   return numberOfCellsYouNeed
   }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath) -> UICollectionVIewCell{
if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"chartCell", for: indexPath) {
cell.addSubView(chartViews[indexPath.row])
return cell
   }else{
return UICollectionViewCell()
}}`

This is the basic way to do it but it might not look very pretty, the next step is to create a custom collectionViewCell class and in InterfaceBuilder you can design it, then in connect outlets in your ChartCell custom class (UICollectionVIewCell) and use this custom cell in the StatsVC. Advantage of a custom cell is that you can have a label at the top/bottom that describes the chart or any other UI element you need. If you keep all your chart Views in an array you can very easily add them to the collectionView with the above method.

**Update**
To create a view programmatically you can do like this:

`let barChartView1 = BarChartView()
let barChartView2 = BarChartView()
barChartView1.data = ...// you do what you need to do here, I'm not familiar with your data/code...
var chartViews = [barChartView1, barChartView2]`

Finally as you see above you can use the indexPath.row as array index to pull out the next chartView and put it in the collectionViewCell. Working with collection nad table views is not exactly a trivial task so I recommend a good night read at the Apple library. Tjios article explains it in detail. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewBasics/CollectionViewBasics.html

Comment: Thanks for the help.But the https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts . describes of only adding the views' class in interface builder.I do not know how to add it programmatically and add it in an array.Could you share me code sample for that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user8986838 did u get any solution?